# Css animation - setTimeout doesn't apply changes which breaks animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Here is the description of my goal:

1. I've got box with `display: none`
2. At some moment I need to display it with `opacity` animation.

Here my solution:
1. `transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;`
2. On first step set `display: block; opacity: 0`
3. On second step set `display: block; opacity: 1`, do it in `setTimeout()` to apply first step.

The problem is that first step applied only in some cases - sometimes it works / sometimes doesn't and browser just skips first step. I thought changing `setTimeout` to `requestAnimationFrame` should fix the problem but it doesn't - [check my example](http://jsfiddle.net/H7EEE/78/)

Why `setTimeout` / `requestAnimationFrame` does not force browser to apply first step? How to force browser to apply first step before applying second one?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sxny7zs2/

`.box{display:none}` should be `.box{display: block;}`

When you set `display:none` you remove the object from the DOM almost entirely. By resetting to `display:block` you bring the object back fully and it begins to interact with other objects. The `display` feature is not meant for animations but for removing objects from interfering with others.

I suspect this is the villain:

`$box.removeClass('is-animate-enter').addClass('is-animate-active');`

By removing `is-animate-enter` class you trigger `display:none;` before you are able to add your next class. This means the object is unloaded from the view. Meanwhile when you do `is-animate-active` you instantly set `display:block` and `opacity:1`. As far as the browser is concerned you are creating a new element, not modifying an old one here. As previously stated, when toggling the `display` you are actually `loading` and `unloading` an object so no animation is possible.

Maybe `.switchClass()` could fix this but I'm not sure, to reiterate the `display` command is for `loading` and `unloading` and not for animations.

Comment: It has to be hidden at the beginning + I set `display: block` by `.box.is-animate-enter`.  My question: why does `setTimeout` work only somites / what's the reason / how to make it stable?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `it works sometimes`. The behavior I see is constant, with or without the `display` assigned. The only difference is it is animated with `display:block;` whereas with `display:none` it just flashes on and off. I will edit my solution with a possible explanation.

Comment: If you play with it you will see that sometimes it DOES work. I updated an example with setTimeout instead of requestAnimationFrame. On my computer it works in most cases in Chrome and doesn't work in FF